# MS Access Inner Join - Concatenation in the ON clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

Working code sample for SQL SERVER

```
Select Top 1 bc.Tier_Name, bc.Unit_ID, bc.Name, bc.Description_2 
FROM bc_subs as bc INNER JOIN Product_V as v
ON  v.ABC = 'ABC: ' + bc.Unit_ID
```

Problem code sample for Access SQL VBA

```
"Select Top 1 bc.Tier_Name, bc.Unit_ID, bc.Name, bc.Description_2 " & _
"FROM bc_subs as bc INNER JOIN Product_V as v" & _
"ON v.ABC = " & "ABC: " & "bc.Unit_ID "
```

In Access, I am trying to INNER JOIN to a table, but part of the join has to concat a string to the front of the value. Table V's key is ABC:123, but the key in BC is just 123 -- so I have to add the ABC: to the font of the 123 to make both sides equal to ABC:123.

I have tried several variations on the VBA Access SQL string but cannot seem to get the join to work correctly.

Any advice? The code was truncated and edited out, variables and alias names changed for safety type reasons.  It is the logic I am after within the VBA code and the assignment of a string to a value like this.

Comment: `INNER JOIN Product_V as v"` <-- you are missing a space after alias `v`.  Fix this, and I'll bet your query will work :-)

Comment: Is that a piece of VBA? If yes, share the full variable assignment (hint: you can already see what's going wrong by looking at the syntax highlighting). If no, why are all those quotes and `& _` there?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nope, there are multiple things wrong with it... I want the full code, because if I can already spot 2 errors in such a small section, there are likely even more to be found.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Oh yeah...there's no `SELECT` clause...I was assuming that everything else we don't see is being done correctly.

Comment: Also quotes missing around ABC: ...etc.

Comment: *"forgive the errors"*: wait, I thought you wanted to know why it didn't work, so how can we know which errors you are aware of? Why not make sure you eliminate all errors you know about, so we don't lose our time with them?

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with either section of code as of your writing trincot. I am not an expert, hence the request for assistance and guidance. I don't know why everyone has to be so harsh here.  shesh.

Comment: @Eric The point is, there are multiple errors to be found. As long as you don't share the actual code, we can't know which one is the actual error, and which ones you've introduced by truncating. You can either try providing an [mcve] if you really can't share the actual code (create a separate database that's not confidential, reproduce the error and share the full code of that DB), or share the actual code. We don't like debugging fictive errors that are only there because you've truncated the code.

Comment: @Erik - Thank you for your link and your constructive feedback.  I guess I was confused because I did provide a sample of working SQL Server code, and a nearly identical but non-functional piece of MS Access VBA SQL.   I will continue to edit my original post to make it more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a space and some quoting:

```
"bc.Tier_Name, bc.Unit_ID, bc.Name, bc.Description_2 " & _
"FROM bc_subs as bc INNER JOIN Product_V as v " & _
"ON v.ABC = 'ABC:' + bc.Unit_ID"
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav.  I tried this out and it isn't quiet right - in my msgbox with the query string - it basically puts & bcUnit_ID & as part of the string itself.  Also, I didn't down vote you.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, but this is still not correct.  It is throwing the + into the sql sting versus using it as a concat function (same with the &'s)

Comment: It can't do that. + is not a literal but a part of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes you're using to concatenate, break your string. You can use double quotes to escape them, and get what's functionally equivalent to your SQL server query.

Also, queries using a join with a constant in the on clause in Access should have the on clause surrounded by parentheses to avoid errors in some conditions. I recommend always using them, to be safe.

```
"Select bc.Tier_Name, bc.Unit_ID, bc.Name, bc.Description_2 " & _
"FROM bc_subs as bc INNER JOIN Product_V as v " & _
"ON (v.ABC = ""ABC: "" & bc.Unit_ID) "
```

Alternatively, you can write this as a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
"Select bc.Tier_Name, bc.Unit_ID, bc.Name, bc.Description_2 " & _
"FROM bc_subs as bc, Product_V as v " & _
"WHERE (v.ABC = ""ABC: "" & bc.Unit_ID) "
```

Comment: Thank you for your input Erik.  This is sadly not working as intended, though I appreciate the assistance.  I understand the functional similarities, and the escaping of the double quotes though it is still not populating any results on the search string.

Comment: That's strange. Note that you do have a significant space there. You can write this as a `CROSS JOIN` and a `WHERE` clause, see the edit. To troubleshoot, you can then remove the `WHERE` clause to see if that returns anything.

Comment: Good idea Erik, I hadn't considered doing it that way.  Removing the WHERE clause does break the query now, which I was not expecting.  the "FROM bc_subs as bc " works , but adding the comma and Poduct_V join (with no where clause) returns zero records (but does work fine in standard MS SQL Server still)

Comment: That's certainly strange. If that table has records, it should return many records. Try to provide an [mcve]. I can't replicate this behavior. Of course, if the tables reside in SQL Server, you could just run a pass-through query and use the working code.